# Diffrence between anonymous class in Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, closures, anonymous-class

I have been learning C# for 2 mouths. Before it, I was learning Java. Can someone explain me what is difference between anonymous class in Java and C#?

All definitions of anonymous class in c# includes delegates, can someone explain me in detail what is difference? Are they the same or only name is similar?

Comment: They have almost no similarities and entirely different use cases. When you say _"All definitions of anonymous class in c# includes delegates"_ you are mistaken as anonymous classes in C# can contain delegate valued properties but this is a rarely-used capability. They are most useful when you want to create an intermediate object with an ad hoc collection properties

Comment: I think you are assuming they have something in common since the word "anonymous" is in both Java's "anonymous inner class" and in C#'s "anonymous type". As @AluanHaddad says, they are entirely different. Java's anonymous inner class can correspond to a C# delegate if the anonymous inner class implements a functional interface - otherwise you would use an explicit class in C# for the general case.

Comment: In C# an anonymous type (we tend not to call them classes) is essentially a data only device - it has properties but nothing else and isn't something you can define explicitly - the compiler makes it for you by inference. In java an anonymous class is much more like a regular class, except you don't get to pick a name or define a constructor. It's like a class you define on the fly to satisfy a demand for something that meets a particular interface. In c# we tend to use delegates for that(if that's what you mean by "includes delegates) but delegates aren't anonymous types